# Append data to JSON Array without replacing the file in Ruby

Tags: arrays, json, ruby

I have the following data in JSON format:

```
{
  "users": [
    {
      "name": "Raj Kumar",
      "email address": "rajkumar@bollywood.com",
      "account type": "manager",
      "permissions": {
        "accounts": "read",
        "approve headcount": "no",
        "manage finance": "yes"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "Johnny Lever",
      "email address": "johnny@lever.com",
      "account type": "accountant",
      "permissions": {
        "accounts": "write",
        "approve headcount": "no",
        "manage finance": "yes"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I know I can use Ruby to get this data into a hash, push another element into the hash and export the hash to replace the existing file. This would mean Ruby would have to import and export the whole JSON file every time we added a new user. Is there a way to do this by simply "appending" the data onto the file without replacing the whole file every single time. (I understand that this technically would not be appending data onto the file.)

That said, are there any recommendations on changing the JSON structure here in order to make for faster additions to the data? I'm thinking of scenarios where this file would have thousands of entries.

Answer (score 0):

You could use YAML instead of JSON. Appending a new element to a YAML file wont require parsing if the root elment is an array

```
:users:
- :name: Raj Kumar
  :email address: rajkumar@bollywood.com
  :account type: manager
  :permissions:
    :accounts: read
    :approve headcount: 'no'
    :manage finance: 'yes'
- :name: Johnny Lever
  :email address: johnny@lever.com
  :account type: accountant
  :permissions:
    :accounts: write
    :approve headcount: 'no'
    :manage finance: 'yes'
```

Comment: YAML::Store can be used for this